# Prevent a syntax file from being sourced?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want to use `filetype=nasm` to get syntax highlighting in assembly files (ending with a `.asm` extension). I have the following autocommand for it:

```
augroup FileTypes
    au!
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.asm :setlocal filetype=nasm
augroup END
```

And it works as intended except for the fact that vim also loads the syntax file for `asm.vim` (which was the default).

```
:scriptnames
```

Is there any way to disable loading this file?

Comment: What makes you believe it is the `asm.vim` that is used? What is the result of `:echo b:current_syntax`

Comment: The syntax being used is `nasm.vim`. My motivation for ignoring `asm.vim` is simply to avoid loading a redundant file of settings.

Comment: The solution of @Matt is then the correct one. the `$VIM\filetype.vim` first decide to associate the `*.asm` to something. There is a logic in `$VIM\autoload\dist\ft.vim` that by default associate to the filetype `asm` but you can override that using `g:asmsyntax` global variable. The logic looks at the first 5 line for a string like `asmsyntax=nasm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set nasm as default assembly syntax simply do

```
let g:asmsyntax = 'nasm'
```

Never forget to read help, i.e. `:h asm.vim` (or `:helpgrep nasm`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the standard syntax from being sourced (unless you remove the file).
But, by introducing your own syntax (`~/.vim/syntax/nasm.vim`), you can make sure it 'override' the standard one.

I your syntax files defines `b:current_syntax` the standard one will do nothing and you should have the effect you want.

```
let b:current_syntax = "nasm"
```

The reason is that, as all standard syntax files, it starts with:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif
```